# Why didn't Ashford shoot Inaros?

Tags: the-expanse-2015

In season 4 episode 10 of The Expanse Ashford corners Inaros and could shoot him, but Filip ambushes him. Filip has a gun pointed at Ashford so if Ashford shoots Inaros then Filip will shoot him. Ashford apparently surrenders and is executed, refusing to bargain for his life.

Given that Ashford is apparently okay with dying and must have known that surrendering would lead to his execution anyway, why not just shoot Inaros?

Comment: If he's going to die, why should he care one way or another?

Answer (score 7):

**Ashford chose to communicate *something* to *somebody* rather than die quietly.**

If Ashford shot Inaros, Filip would shoot Ashford and no one would ever hear anything further from Ashford.  However, after being spaced out the airlock, we see Ashford's wrist-mounted communicator first "Sending" and then "Message Sent".  Presumably he used his time before being spaced to subtly key in or record a message, then sent it as he was being ejected from the ship.

What was he sending, and to whom?  We don't know.  But maybe it was something more valuable than Inaros' life, such as information about the ship or something he learned while on the ship that will help foil Inaros' plans.

[image: Sending]

[image: Message Sent]

(Images flipped 180 degrees; in the video the words are upside-down).

Comment: Oh yes! I forgot, he recorded Inaros revealing his evil plan, like all evil masterminds love to. He said he doesn't care about the belt or Mars.